# I seem to be dropping my last input

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a function to take in all of the values entered on a line, ignoring commas, and store them into a vector.

Then I need the vector to print them back. I am new to C++ and after diving through a few tutorials and learning a few little tricks I managed to get every bug out of it but one.

I can't get the last number to appear. It will display all of them, except the last number before enter is pushed.

Is there a way to get the last one to work or do I need to have the entire line stored to a string and searched that way?

This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void fillVector(vector<int>&);
void printVector(const vector<int>&);

int main()
{

    vector<int>myVector;
    fillVector(myVector);
    printVector(myVector);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void fillVector(vector<int>& newMyVector) {
    cout << "Please type in a series of numbers separated by a comma, and press Enter when done." << endl;
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    while (cin.peek()!= '\n') {
        newMyVector.push_back(input);
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ',');
        cin >> input;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void printVector(const vector<int>& myNewVector) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myNewVector.size(); i++){
        if (i <= myNewVector.size() - 2) {
            cout << myNewVector[i] << ", ";
        }
        else {
            cout << myNewVector[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I am very new to c++, and It would appear as though the loop would grab the last number and insert it into the vector, but it seems to skip it.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that `push_back` is never called for the last `input`.  This is because the new `input` is read in during the `while` loop but only at the end.  You can make it work by checking the `while` at the end with a `do` loop.  Or reading the `input` at the start of the loop and then `push_back`.

```
do {
    cin >> input;
    newMyVector.push_back(input);
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ',');
} while(cin.peek() != '\n');
```

Or

```
void fillVector(vector<int>& newMyVector) {
cout << "Please type in a series of numbers separated by a comma, and press Enter when done." << endl;
int input;
while (cin.peek()!= '\n') {
    cin >> input;        
    newMyVector.push_back(input);
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ',');
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Both of these are basically the same.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I knew it was probably something simple, and sure enough it was.  I got it working, now all i have to do is edit the instructions to add a comma to the end so it stops searching, but now i have a place to move forward.  Thanks again!